# How to identify whether an anchor tag is rendered using a react-router-dom Link tag or a normal anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, anchor

Pretty much the question . I need to distinguish between normal achor tags and React routers link tags for my application. I do see that Link tags have one extra click listener `noop` . But im not sure if thats a good criteria for distinguishing between two.

```
function noop() {}
```

Lets say this was a client site using react-router-dom . Now i need to know which is link and which is normal anchor

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="about">React Link tag 1</Link>
      <br>
      <a href="about">Normal anchor 6</a>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="about" element={ <About/> } />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this differentiation? Is this a CSS targeting issue? Something else?

Comment: In which context? Inside a browser or inside the file system?

Comment: @Andy its for a WSIWYG website editor that lets you edit everything including href's of anchor tags. In case its a normal anchor tag everything is simple. In case of Link tags react takes control despite having explicit href so we have to replace the whole element including listeners . This isnt ideal and we only want to do this for Link tag elements and not normal anchor elements .

Comment: @Camilo its in browser